# Get requests from website

Tags: python, networking

I'm trying to intercept all the requests received by a website, to get a certain file. For example, when you use Firefox's network monitor. Can I do that in Python? Sorry for being so vague. I'd like to get all the URLs that the website requests, like you can see in the picture. Example: the favicon, js files, xml files, etc.

Example:

[image: Firefox -> Tools -> Dev Tools > Network]

Comment: So you want to monitor all requests sent **to** a website? The website itself isn't sending any requests. Please [edit] your question to include a *concrete* example of what you want to monitor, when, and between which parties. Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm bad at explaining myself. I need to get all the URLs the website requests, for example: the favicon, the images, js files, xml files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

So you probably need a packet sniffer like tcpdump. The best python sniffer I know is scapy. Here is in example of how HTTP may be sniffed with it:
http://www.r00tsec.com/2013/12/simple-sniffer-http-request-and-http.html

Note that you couldn't do that trick with HTTPS. Also packet sniffing usually requires root privileges on a host system.